# Difference between @Mock and @InjectMocks

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

What is the difference between `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` in Mockito framework?

Comment: useful resource https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/

Answer (score 882):

`@Mock` creates a mock. `@InjectMocks` creates an instance of the class and injects the mocks that are created with the `@Mock` (or `@Spy`) annotations into this instance.

Note you must use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` or `Mockito.initMocks(this)` to initialize these mocks and inject them (JUnit 4).

With JUnit 5, you must use `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) // JUnit 4
// @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) for JUnit 5
public class SomeManagerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private SomeManager someManager;

    @Mock
    private SomeDependency someDependency; // this will be injected into someManager
 
     // tests...

}
```

Comment: Does this work for transitive dependencies or only direct members?

Comment: @PierreThibault Injecting mocks only works for direct members, but you can set a mock to allow deep stubs https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS

Comment: i feel this is much clear than most of the article online.... that little comments save my ass...

Comment: I have some items that can not provided by @Mock annotation like context. How i can provide that for main class?

Comment: ...and now `Mockito.initMocks(this)` is deprecated, `Mockito.openMocks(this)` should be used.

Comment: I think for `JUnit 5`, if your test is `@SpringBootTest`, the described `@ExtendWith` isn't necessary (@SpringBootTest does its own @ExtendWith [of `SpringExtension.class`])

Comment: @Cellepo Add a citation when you claim https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing.spring-boot-applications

Comment: This: `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class RoleServiceImplTest {
    @InjectMocks
    RoleServiceImpl roleService;
    @Mock
    RoleDao roleDao;`

Comment: gives an exception: `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnnecessaryStubbingException: 
Unnecessary stubbings detected.
Clean & maintainable test code requires zero unnecessary code.
Following stubbings are unnecessary (click to navigate to relevant line of code):
  1. -> at pp.spring_bootstrap.service.RoleServiceImplTest.setUp(RoleServiceImplTest.java:29)
Please remove unnecessary stubbings or use 'lenient' strictness. More info: javadoc for UnnecessaryStubbingException class.`

Answer (score 460):

This is a sample code on how `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` works.

Say we have `Game` and `Player` class.

```
class Game {

    private Player player;

    public Game(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
    }

    public String attack() {
        return "Player attack with: " + player.getWeapon();
    }

}

class Player {

    private String weapon;

    public Player(String weapon) {
        this.weapon = weapon;
    }

    String getWeapon() {
        return weapon;
    }
}
```

As you see, `Game` class need `Player` to perform an `attack`.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class GameTest {

    @Mock
    Player player;

    @InjectMocks
    Game game;

    @Test
    public void attackWithSwordTest() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(player.getWeapon()).thenReturn("Sword");

        assertEquals("Player attack with: Sword", game.attack());
    }

}
```

Mockito will mock a Player class and it's behaviour using `when` and `thenReturn` method. Lastly, using `@InjectMocks` Mockito will put that `Player` into `Game`.

Notice that you don't even have to create a `new Game` object. Mockito will inject it for you.

```
// you don't have to do this
Game game = new Game(player);
```

We will also get same behaviour using `@Spy` annotation. Even if the attribute name is different.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class GameTest {

  @Mock Player player;

  @Spy List<String> enemies = new ArrayList<>();

  @InjectMocks Game game;

  @Test public void attackWithSwordTest() throws Exception {
    Mockito.when(player.getWeapon()).thenReturn("Sword");

    enemies.add("Dragon");
    enemies.add("Orc");

    assertEquals(2, game.numberOfEnemies());

    assertEquals("Player attack with: Sword", game.attack());
  }
}

class Game {

  private Player player;

  private List<String> opponents;

  public Game(Player player, List<String> opponents) {
    this.player = player;
    this.opponents = opponents;
  }

  public int numberOfEnemies() {
    return opponents.size();
  }

  // ...
```

That's because Mockito will check the `Type Signature` of Game class, which is `Player` and `List<String>`.

Comment: I sometimes find the testing with the mocking hard to understand and design for a class. However, this example helps a lot to provide the overview.

Comment: Probably too late to this thread but just in case someone sees this: What if the class I am doing an @Mock on itself has some dependencies that need to be injected?

For example, say if the weapon was actually a class instead of a String?

Comment: @MarcoPolo - see [this comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467685/difference-between-mock-and-injectmocks#comment100441274_16467893)

Answer (score 90):

In your test class, the tested class should be annotated with `@InjectMocks`. This tells Mockito which class to inject mocks into:

```
@InjectMocks
private SomeManager someManager;
```

From then on, we can specify which specific methods or objects inside the class, in this case, `SomeManager`, will be substituted with mocks:

```
@Mock
private SomeDependency someDependency;
```

In this example, `SomeDependency` inside the `SomeManager` class will be mocked.

Comment: will this work if someManager has more then one constructor ? what if someManager had 5 constructors how would it know which one you want to use ?

Answer (score 74):

`@Mock` annotation mocks the concerned object.

`@InjectMocks` annotation allows to inject into the underlying object the different (and relevant) mocks created by `@Mock`.

**Both are complementary.**

Comment: Can they be used in tandem on the same object?

Comment: Do you have a mini-example of your requirement?

Comment: I have a class that needs to be spied on (via Mockito Spy), and this class has a constructor.  So I was thinking of using `@InjectMocks` to construct this class and spy on it too.

Comment: Is that what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/a/35969166/985949

Answer (score 36):

- **@Mock** creates a mock implementation for the classes you need.
- **@InjectMock**  creates an instance of the class and injects the mocks that are marked with the annotations **@Mock** into it.

For example

```
@Mock
StudentDao studentDao;

@InjectMocks
StudentService service;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Here we need the DAO class for the service class. So, we mock it and inject it in the service class instance.
Similarly, in Spring framework all the **@Autowired** beans can be mocked by **@Mock** in jUnits and injected into your bean through @InjectMocks.

`MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` method initialises these mocks and injects them for every test method so it needs to be called in the `setUp()` method.

[This link has a good tutorial for Mockito framework](https://dzone.com/articles/a-guide-to-mocking-with-mockito)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This is the first answer I read that made me understand a little better the difference between them.

Answer (score 14):

A "mocking framework", which Mockito is based on, is a framework that gives you the ability to create Mock objects ( in old terms these objects could be called shunts, as they work as shunts for dependend functionality ) 
In other words, a mock object is used to imitate the real object your code is dependend on, you create a proxy object with the mocking framework.
By using mock objects in your tests you are essentially going from normal unit testing to integrational testing

Mockito is an open source testing framework for Java released under the MIT License, it is a "mocking framework", that lets you write beautiful tests with clean and simple API. There are many different mocking frameworks in the Java space, however there are essentially two main types of mock object frameworks, ones that are implemented via proxy and ones that are implemented via class remapping.

Dependency injection frameworks like Spring allow you to inject your proxy objects without modifying any code, the mock object expects a certain method to be called and it will return an expected result.

The `@InjectMocks` annotation tries to instantiate the testing object instance and injects fields annotated with `@Mock` or `@Spy` into private fields of the testing object.

`MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` call, resets testing object and re-initializes mocks, so remember to have this at your `@Before` / `@BeforeMethod` annotation.

Comment: I would not say that "By using mock objects in your tests you are essentially going from normal unit testing to integrational testing". For me, mocking is to isolate the fixture to be tested in order to unit-test. Integration testing will use real not mocked dependencies.

Comment: @WesternGun I don't understand how your understanding of mocking is different from the part you quoted

Comment: Mocking is a typical UNIT testing procedure. Integration tests use the real dependencies. This is the plus to unit tests. It run in the real environment, not in an imitated special one to test one case.

Answer (score 14):

Though the above answers have covered, I have just tried to add minute detail s which i see missing. The reason behind them(The Why).

[image]

---

**Illustration:**

```
Sample.java
---------------
    public class Sample{
        DependencyOne dependencyOne;
        DependencyTwo dependencyTwo;


        public SampleResponse methodOfSample(){
            dependencyOne.methodOne();
            dependencyTwo.methodTwo();

            ...

            return sampleResponse;
        }
    }
```

---

```
SampleTest.java
-----------------------
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ClassA.class})
public class SampleTest{

    @InjectMocks
    Sample sample;

    @Mock
    DependencyOne dependencyOne;

    @Mock
    DependencyTwo dependencyTwo;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    public void sampleMethod1_Test(){
        //Arrange the dependencies
        DependencyResponse dependencyOneResponse = Mock(sampleResponse.class);
        Mockito.doReturn(dependencyOneResponse).when(dependencyOne).methodOne();

        DependencyResponse dependencyTwoResponse = Mock(sampleResponse.class);
        Mockito.doReturn(dependencyOneResponse).when(dependencyTwo).methodTwo();

        //call the method to be tested
        SampleResponse sampleResponse = sample.methodOfSample() 

        //Assert
        <assert the SampleResponse here>
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://howtodoinjava.com/mockito/mockito-mock-injectmocks/)

Answer (score 13):

[image]

`@Mock` is for creating and injecting mock instances without having to call Mockito.mock manually. In this example the instance would be **ClassB**.

Whereas, @`InjectMocks` is for injecting mock fields into the tested object automatically. In this case it would be **ClassA**

Answer (score 10):

One advantage you get with the approach mentioned by @Tom is that you don't have to create any constructors in the SomeManager, and hence limiting the clients to instantiate it.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeManagerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private SomeManager someManager;

    @Mock
    private SomeDependency someDependency; // this will be injected into someManager

    //You don't need to instantiate the SomeManager with default contructor at all
   //SomeManager someManager = new SomeManager();    
   //Or SomeManager someManager = new SomeManager(someDependency);

     //tests...

}
```

Whether its a good practice or not depends on your application design.

Comment: what if someManager had 3 different constructors, how would it know which one to use ?

Comment: How do you then verify stuff on **someManager** if it is not mocked?

Answer (score 10):

`@Mock` is used to declare/mock the references of the dependent beans, while `@InjectMocks` is used to mock the bean for which test is being created.

For example:

```
public class A{

   public class B b;

   public void doSomething(){

   }

}
```

test for class `A`:

```
public class TestClassA{

   @Mocks
   public class B b;

   @InjectMocks
   public class A a;

   @Test
   public testDoSomething(){

   }

}
```

Answer (score 10):

@InjectMocks annotation can be used to inject mock fields into a test object automatically.

In below example @InjectMocks has used to inject the mock dataMap into the dataLibrary .

```
@Mock
Map<String, String> dataMap ;

@InjectMocks
DataLibrary dataLibrary = new DataLibrary();


    @Test
    public void whenUseInjectMocksAnnotation_() {
        Mockito.when(dataMap .get("aData")).thenReturn("aMeaning");

        assertEquals("aMeaning", dataLibrary .getMeaning("aData"));
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Many people have given a great explanation here about `@Mock` vs `@InjectMocks`. I like it, but I think our tests and application should be written in such a way that we shouldn't need to use `@InjectMocks`.

Reference for further reading with examples: https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/

Comment: This one seems to be a long term solution.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that that `@InjectMocks` are about to be [deprecated](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1518)

> deprecate @InjectMocks and schedule for removal in Mockito 3/4

and you can follow @avp [answer and link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467685/difference-between-mock-and-injectmocks/51870960#51870960) on:

> Why You Should Not Use InjectMocks Annotation to Autowire Fields