# Injection an object though InjectMocks Spy

Tags: java, mockito, spy

I need to run series of unit tests over a class, which has a @Autowired Logger implementation. The base idea of realization was:

```
@Mock Logger logger;
@InjectMocks
TestedClass tested;
```

but i want to save the logging output functionality.

Does Mockito lib allow to inject objects with @InjectMock? I'w seen examples of @Spy annotation, but when i tried to use it, i always got NullPointerException. I know that i can always directly use reflect, but the idea is to avoid such code.

Answer (score 5):

Well. I'll have to answer it myself if there's no answers.

To push a live object through the @InjectMock annotation a @Spy annotation is used:

```
@Spy
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("");
@InjectMocks
TestedClass tested = new TestedClass();
```

The only thing is that @Spy cant handle final(and some other things) classes, on which i struck on in my case.