# Entity JpaRepository method doesn't work during testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

I have a service method in my Java Spring server that's supposed to save the user to the DB.

```
@Override
public User addUser(User user) {
    log.info("Saving new user {} to the database", user.getUsername());
    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    return userRepository.save(user);

}
```

And then I have the test class.

```
@Slf4j
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class UserTest {
@InjectMocks
UserServiceImpl userService;

@Mock
private UserRepository userRepository;
@Mock
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource({
        "username, password, 1, test@test.com, admin, true",
})
void checkIfUserCanBeAdded(String username,String password,int group_id,String email,String role,Boolean active){
    
    //given
    User user = new User(username, password, group_id, email, role, active);

    //when
    User result = userService.addUser(user);

    //then
    assertSame(result.getUsername(),user.getUsername());
    assertSame(result.getPassword(), user.getPassword());
    assertSame(result.getGroup_id(), user.getGroup_id());
    assertSame(result.getEmail(), user.getEmail());
    assertSame(result.getEmail(), user.getEmail());
    }
}
```

But apparently the userRepository.save() method returns null

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "sensor.management.sensor_admin.domain.entity.User.getUsername()" because "result" is null
```

What's the solution to it? Why it doesn't work?

Edit: I decided to changed the test to the code bellow,and it works as it is right now

```
    @BeforeEach
    public void setup(){
        user = new User(1,"username", "password", 1, "test@test.com", "admin", true);
    }

    @Test
    void checkIfUserCanBeAdded(){

        //given
        given(userRepository.save(user)).willReturn(user);

        //when
        User savedUser = userService.addUser(user);

        assertNotNull(savedUser);
    }
```

Comment: you are creating a mock of the userRepository so you neeed to tell your test what to return after hiting userRepository.save()

Comment: you didn't mock method calls - https://stackoverflow.com/a/39436666/4778343

Comment: Is there any other way to inject the dependencies while creating UserServiceImpl instance? And if we are talking about mock and what you said, how to tell the test what to return

Comment: Stefan Golubović linked you the page on what to do

Answer (score 0):

Please add below statements before `User result = userService.addUser(user);` and try again.

```
Mockito.when(passwordEncoder.encode(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(user.getPassword());
Mockito.when(userRepository.save(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(user);
```

Comment: I get this ```org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnnecessaryStubbingException: 
Unnecessary stubbings detected.``` It's pointing at the return line in the service method

Comment: Can you please share full stacktrace. I think it is giving this error for PasswordEncoder. You can remove PasswordEncoder mock and try again

Comment: @m3k_1 - Any update on this, please? is your issue resolved?

Comment: @rohit_agarwal I chenged the test, check the question

Comment: Ok still same issue?

Comment: @rohit_agarwal As of now, no. If the test is written like that it's ok