# org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException

Tags: java, mockito

I have tried below lines

```
@Test
public void getXYZ_Success() throws Exception  {
    Response result=abc.XYZ(exampleHeader);
    Response response=new Response(); 
    response.setMessage(null);
    response.setStatusCode("01");
    response.setStatus("Failure");

    List<ExampleFilterLkp> exampleFilterList=new ArrayList<exampleFilterLkp>();
    exampleFilterLkp exampleFilterLkp=new exampleFilterLkp();
    examplFilterLkp.setexampleKey("1");
    exampleList.add(exampleFilterLkp);      
    doReturn(response).when(result);
}
```

I'm getting below error, how to solve this issue, please help me

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
>   Argument passed to when() is not a mock!
>   Example of correct stubbing:
>       doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someMethod();
>       at com.firstdata.mpl.manager.exampleTest.getexampleFilter_NullFailure(FuelManagerTest.java:184)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:670)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Comment: I think the message is pretty clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exception message says that argument passed to when() is not a mock.

In this case, it's a `result`

```
doReturn(response).when(result);
```

Exception message even says what a correct invocation should look like:

```
Example of correct stubbing:
doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someMethod();
```

It isn't clear from the question what is being tested here. If `abc` is a mock object and you want to return the `response` on `XYZ` call then something like this should work:

```
doReturn(response).when(abc).XYZ(exampleHeader);
```

Otherwise, you need to explain what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I tried doReturn(response).when(abc).XYZ(exampleHeader); but throwing error not a mock object

Comment: Can you include `abc` initialization in your question? Also, please, add some explanation: what exactly are you trying to mock/test?

Comment: I put @InjectMock annotation for the abc, but no use

Comment: @InjectMocks
private ABC abc;
is the abc initialization

Comment: @Karthick probably, you should use `@Mock` annotation. Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467685/difference-between-mock-and-injectmocks

Comment: @Mock
 private ABC abc; is resolved my issue thanks for your help default locale

Comment: Once again thanks for your help , it resolved my issue, thank you "default locale" :-)

Comment: @Karthick You're welcome. Don't forget [to accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I have a method below  public Response getAbcExample(Double a, Double b, Integer c, String d, RequestHeader requestHeader)
   throws  {
  Map<String, String> logMap = new HashMap<>();
  Response response = new Response();
  String jsonString = _getAB_Exampe(a, b, c, requestHeader);
 } my mockito lines are below Mockito.verify(abc, Mockito.times(1)).getAbcExample(Mockito.any(Double.class),Mockito.any(Double.class),Mockito.any(Integer.class),Mockito.eq(""),Mockito.any(RequestHeader.class)); but am getting InvalidUseOfMatchersException please help me

Answer (score 1):

`result` object is not a mock object. `when` needs a mock object as an arg --> when(mock)