# How do I mock static member variables of a class using Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a class like this:

```
public class CloudFormationManager
{
    private static CloudFormationManager cloudFormationManager;
    private final AmazonCloudFormation amazonCloudFormation;

    private CloudFormationManager(final AmazonCloudFormation amazonCloudFormation)
    {
        this.amazonCloudFormation = amazonCloudFormation;
    }

    public List<StackResource> getStackResources(final String stackName)
    {
        ListStackResourcesRequest listStackResourcesRequest = new ListStackResourcesRequest();
        listStackResourcesRequest.setStackName(stackName);
        ListStackResourcesResult listStackResourcesResult =
                amazonCloudFormation.listStackResources(listStackResourcesRequest);

        if (nonNull(listStackResourcesResult))
            return getStackResources(listStackResourcesResult);
        else
            return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

I am beginning to write UT's for this using Mockito which is as follows:

```
@Test
public class CloudFormationManagerTest
{
    @Mock
    private AmazonCloudFormation amazonCloudFormation;

    @InjectMocks
    CloudFormationManager cloudFormationManager;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws IOException
    {
        CloudFormationManager cloudFormationManager = new CloudFormationManager(amazonCloudFormation); // this statement gives an error.
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    void testGetStackResources()
    {

    }

}
```

Now, in the `setUp()` method, I see an error saying that this class cannot be initialised and I understand this since it's a private constructor? How do I initialise it then using Mockito?

Comment: You need `PowerMockito` instead, please have a quick google search.

Comment: How do you initialize it in app code? Don't you need a builder / factory method? Something like `CloudFormationManager.create(AmazonCloudFormation acf)`

Comment: You probably _don't_ need PowerMockito.  However your actual application creates a `CloudFormationManager` would be something you need to replicate in your test.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem, but I am writing the UT for that class itself. Will I have to inject CloudFormationManager in the class itself?

Comment: Also, with just a little bit of extra design work you could increase testablity and eliminate the need for mocking. Mocking is usually expensive (in development time), brittle, and not particularly valuable.

Comment: What I'm saying is - it must be possible to create a `CloudFormationManager`, because your application presumably does it.  So however you've created it, do the same thing in the test.

Comment: Yep, sorry got it. It has been done like this, `CloudFormationManager.getInstance(amazonCloudFormation);`. Are you suggesting I should do a similar thing inside the setUp() method then?

Comment: Yes.  And pass in your mock AmazonCloudFormation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not clear on what `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` does.

Using `@Mock`, you create a *mocked* object. Using `@InjectMocks`, you have Mockito *insert* all `@Mock` objects into some object under test.

Your class `CloudFormationManager` has **two** fields. Thus you would *probably* need:

```
@Mock
private AmazonCloudFormation mockedAmazonCloud;

@Mock
CloudFormationManager mockedFormationManager;

@InjectMocks
CloudFormationManager cloudFormationManager;
```

and now Mockito should setup both fields upon calling `initAnnotiations()`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467685/difference-between-mock-and-injectmocks) for further reading.