# How to test a filter in a java application using mockito

Tags: java, web, filter, mockito

I have filter:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    User user = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute(Attribute.ATTRIBUTE_USER);
    if (user == null) {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
        response.sendRedirect("/controller?command=goToError");
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
```

And I have my test:

```
@Mock
private FilterChain filterChain;
@Mock
private HttpSession sessionTest;
@Mock
private User userTest;
@Mock
private UserFilter userFilterTest;
@Mock
private ServletResponse servletResponse;
@Mock
private ServletRequest servletRequest;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testDoFilter() {
    Mockito.doReturn(userTest).when(sessionTest).getAttribute(Attribute.ATTRIBUTE_USER);
    try {
        userFilterTest.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse, filterChain);
        verify(filterChain).doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    } catch (IOException | ServletException e) {
        fail();
    }
}
```

I dont know what is the problem with my test. Writes that the method which in verify() has never been called. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems userFilterTest is mock. Please mark

```
@InjectMocks 
private UserFilter userFilterTest;
```

see the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467685/difference-between-mock-and-injectmocks)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunate you do not *log* the  the exception.

If you did you would see a `ClassCastException` occurring at

> ```
> HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
> ```

The reason is the your mock has the wrong type:

> ```
> @Mock
> private ServletRequest servletRequest;
> ```

instead of

```
@Mock
private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
```

The same is true for the `servletResponse`.

## Conclusion

- never swallow exceptions!
- no not use `try`/`catch` in unittest

if your test looked like this

@Test

```
public void testDoFilter() throws Exception{
   Mockito.doReturn(userTest).when(sessionTest).getAttribute(Attribute.ATTRIBUTE_USER);
        userFilterTest.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse, filterChain);
        verify(filterChain).doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
}
```

it would have failed with the `ClassCastException`.