# JUnit does not recognize @Test cases defined in a concrete implementation of Abstract class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, abstract-class

This is a weird situation I am facing in JUnit.

**Given :**

1. I needed to create Unit tests to test the methods defined in an abstract class.
2. For this, I created a **ConcreteAbstractClassImpl** which extended the **AbstractClass** and provided **dummy responses** for the abstract methods in it.
3. To define tests, I created a test class **ConcreteAbstractClassImplTest**. All non-abstract methods of AbstractClass were unit tested in this class using **@Test**.

Code sample provided below :

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class AbstractClassTest {
    @Mock
    private DependencyClass dependencyClassObj;

    @InjectMocks
    private ConcreteAbstractClassImpl concreteAbstractClassImpl ;

    @Before
    public void setUP() {
       .........
    }

    @Test
    public void test_non_abstract_method_AbstractClassImpl () {
         String response = concreteAbstractClassImpl.method_non_abstract();
         assertEquals(response, "method_non_abstract");
    }
}

class ConcreteAbstractClassImpl extends AbstractClass {
     private DependencyClass dependencyClassObj;

     public abstract String method_abstract(){
           return "dummy_response";
     }
}

class AbstractClass {
     @Autowired
     private DependencyClass dependencyClassObj;

     public abstract String method_abstract();

     public String method_non_abstract(){
         return "method_non_abstract";
     }
}
```

**Problem :**
The test class runs perfectly and recognizes each test case when run individually in Eclipse via **Run As > Junit Test**. But when I build the whole project using **Run As > Maven Build** on pom.xml and **unchecking Skip Tests**, all the tests mentioned in **ConcreteAbstractClassImplTest** are ignored by JUnit. Regular test classes which do not follow the above pattern are recognized correctly by JUnit. I don't know if this is a bug or something in JUnit but would be of great help if someone had a workaround/fix for this.

This issue is also affecting my Sonar coverage due to the test classes being skipped.

Comment: why are you mocking the class you are trying to test?

Comment: no i am not. the class i need to test is AbstractClass whos concrete implementation is ConcreteAbstractClassImpl --> for which I have created ConcreteAbstractClassImplTest in which I mock the "DependencyClass object" and inject it into ConcreteAbstractClassImpl using InjectMocks. So confusing, I know. :D

Comment: according to this thread, you are using the wrong runner (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467685/difference-between-mock-and-injectmocks?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: If by this u mean, I should be using MockitoJUnitRunner instead of PowerMockRunner, please note that I tried and it didn't work. :(

Comment: do you have any testclass with these annotations that work?

Comment: "Regular test classes which do not follow the above pattern are recognized correctly by JUnit". By regular ones, I mean the ones annotated by @PowerMockRunner but not testing an abstract class via dummy  concreteImpl as above.

Comment: That's not what I asked. Do you have test classes using these that actually work? Also: why would you test abstract classes? They'll never "work" in their own private scope, since they are, you know, abstract

Comment: Try renaming your class. Looks like it's a problem with JUnit in not picking up classes with Abstract keyword on the front