# org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException in MOCKITO

Tags: java, kotlin, mockito

I am having a simple controller class

```
@RestController
open class MyController() {

@Autowired
lateinit var myInterface: MyInterface

@GetMapping(value = ["/v1/call-Api"], produces = ["application/json"])
fun getData():Response{
   callFx()
   /// Here I have logic
 }

  fun callFx():String{
    return myInterface.getmyStringData()
  }
}
```

Now Come to implementation part of

> MyInterface

```
@Service
class MyImpl: MyInterface {
  override fun getmyStringData(){
        return "Some string"
    }
}
```

Please note that for **MyInterface**, I have only one implementation class.

Now come to Test case of controller class

```
class ControllerTest{

@Autowired
lateinit var myIntF: Myinterface


@Test
fun controllerTest(){         
Mockito.`when`(myIntF.getmyStringData()).thenReturn("Some mock string")
// Some code over here
}

}
```

After all these I am keep getting below error

```
  org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
  when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
  For example:
  when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

  Also, this error might show up because:
  1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
  Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
  Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
  2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
```

Even though code syntax belongs to Kotlin but i keep it simple to elaborate me scenario. Any JAVA guy can also help me.

Any help would be really helpful for me.

Comment: Are you using another `@Profile` for your tests? How do you define `Myinterface` as a mock?

Answer (score 3):

**The problem:**

Below is your test class

```
class ControllerTest{

@Autowired
lateinit var myIntF: MyInterface


@Test
fun controllerTest(){         
Mockito.`when`(myIntF.getmyStringData()).thenReturn("Some mock string")
// Some code over here
}
```

Since you have used `@Autowired`, the real implementation is used and not the mock object and hence when you do `Mockito.when(myIntF.getmyStringData()).thenReturn("Some mock string")`
, you get the error `when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'`. This is because `myIntF` is not a mock object.

**The solution:**

First, since it's a controller test, you need to have the controller field annotated with `@InjectMocks` to inject the mocked `MyInterface` obj into it. Then you need to annotate the `MyInterface` field with `@Mock` which would create a mocked object. Then you need to have a `@Before` or `@BeforeEach` method with `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` to initialize objects annotated with Mockito annotations. Only after that, the method call mocking with `Mockito.when(mockedObject.methodCall).thenReturn(mockedValue)` would work.

```
class ControllerTest{

@InjectMocks
lateinit var controller: MyController

@Mock
lateinit var myIntF: MyInterface

@BeforeEach
fun init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
}


@Test
fun controllerTest(){         
    Mockito.`when`(myIntF.getmyStringData()).thenReturn("Some mock string")
    // Some code over here
    controller.callFx() //this would return "Some mock string"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `@Autowire` so this might be a completely wrong assumption, but it's also too big for a comment, so here it goes.

The exception basically explains that the object you're trying to mock isn't a mock and from what I can see, this is true.

Usually one can do something like:

```
@Mock
lateinit var myIntF: Myinterface

@Before
fun setUp() {
  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
}
```

And now the mock is created and you can configure it with `when` like you have.

There are other options to initialize this, such as running the test with [the mockito test runner](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.28/org/mockito/junit/MockitoJUnitRunner.html). I believe there's also a test rule and you'll always have [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin) which is great for kotlin code and it's much simpler in my personal opinion:

```
lateinit var myIntF = mock<Myinterface>()

@Test
fun controllerTest(){ 
  myIntF.stub {
   on { getmyStringData() } doReturn "Some mock string"
  }
}
```

The point here is that I think you didn't actually create a mock and mockito needs this because if I'm not mistaken it works by inheriting from the class it's mocking.

*Edit*:

As pointed out in the comments you might want to test the controller. This means you'll need to instantiate it with the mocks you've created. One suggested way is to use `@InjectMocks`. Something like:

```
@InjectMocks
lateinit var controller: MyController
```

But without knowing the whole test code it's hard to say this is exactly what you want.

Comment: @Fred..Thanks for response but it's calling actual Implementation. Ideally when mocking or stubbing has been done then actual implementation shouldn't  be get call..But thanks agian..

Comment: That's definitely not possible. First it's an interface, so it can't be calling the actual implementation and second, `mock` does not call the real implementation ever. You'd have to use a `spy` and actually create the instance yourself. Please check that there are no another things interfering, such as the `Autowired` annotation.

Comment: @jhon actually reading what auto wired does, it sounds like if you keep it in the test it'll inject your mock with the defined implementation. I don't think you want that, so I guess you want to remove that annotation?

Comment: The answer seems correct, but it's also necessary to add the annotation `@InjectMocks` to the controller in the test, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/16467685/6245535

Comment: @Loris Securo that might be true. I just didn't see any instance of the controller in the code so wasn't sure where the mock was going. I can update the answer if I know exactly how the mock should be used