# NullInsteadOfMockException when stub a function

Tags: spring-boot, mockito

In my springboot project, I am testing some POJOs using `Mockito`.

I simply mock instance & stub function:

```
public class MyCarTest {
   @Mock
   Car car;

   @Mock
   Manufacture manufacture;

   @Test
   public void testGetManufacture() {
      // NullInsteadOfMockException
      doReturn(manufacture).when(car).getManufacture();

   }
}
```

if I run the test, I get error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NullInsteadOfMockException: 
Argument passed to when() is null!
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: That is because the mock object `car` is not initialized. Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60950079/org-mockito-exceptions-misusing-missingmethodinvocationexception-in-mockito/61033150#61033150) of mine and see if it helps.

Comment: Basically you need `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` or the test class annotated with a runner for initializing the mock object.

Comment: did the above help?