# Different ways of mocking object creation in Mockito?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I see a couple different ways of mocking objects. What exactly are the differences between this approache using InjectMocks and the approach shown here: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Mocking-Object-Creation?

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyTest() {
    @Mock ClassB uut;
    @InjectMocks ClassA cA;
    @Test
    public TestOne() {
        ...
    }
}
```

where

```
public class ClassA() {
    public ClassA() {
        ClassB temp = new ClassB();
    }
}
```

versus the method shown here:
https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Mocking-Object-Creation

What exactly is the difference?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between @Mock and @InjectMocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467685/difference-between-mock-and-injectmocks)

Comment: @Progman No it doesn't. Why would it answer it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is no essential difference between those approaches.

## InjectMocks approach

Actually for it to work, your class should accept the dependencies through the constructor or setters (and it never works with both). I would say that this approach makes the testing easier because you inject whatever you want to your class object at the initialization phase.

```java
class Foo {
    private final Bar bar;

    public Foo(final Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }  
}
```

If this is our class under test, then all @InjectMock does is to create mocks, and do the following:

```java
Foo foo = new Foo(barMock);
```

Apart from being testable, imagine if the `Bar` is an interface, then you can possibly you can switch between multiple implementations of it without actually touching the class code (ideally). If you have a DI framework, that's even easier. So, basically this format of the class makes it flexible.

## Using one-line methods for object creation

Let's say this is our class under test. As you can see, I am initializing the property inside the constructor. Legally, with no reflection magic, I cannot put a mock `bar` variable neither during initialization nor after that.

```java
class Foo {
    private final Bar bar;

    public Foo() {
        this.bar = new Bar();
    }  
}
```

The reason that Mockito docs tell you to switch to either a one-liner method or a Factory helper is that:

- Mockito cannot mock constructors, which means you cannot put a mock object in the place of `bar` without reflection, and you can only do that after the initialization. Generally, to point of my view on testing, reflection should be avoided as much as possible.
- One-liner functions are looking as clean as constructors and they can be descriptive (like static factory methods).

So, when you switch your class to look like this:

```java
class Foo {
    private final Bar bar;

    public Foo() {
        this.bar = makeBar();
    } 

    Bar makeBar() {
      return new Bar();
    } 
}
```

Now, you can put a spy, and just mock the `makeBar` method easily. The same applies to the factory method as well. To be honest, the factory approach looks a bit wordy to me, but still, I am sure there will be times when it may come handy.