# Mockito how does @InjectMocks works

Tags: java, junit, mockito

From this [Difference between @Mock and @InjectMocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467685/difference-between-mock-and-injectmocks)  I understand that @InjectMocks is used as an annotation for
create an instance and inject the mocks that are created with @Mock into it.
I don't think I understand how it works.

I have an example code on which I would like to ask you 2 questions in order to go straight to the points that are not clear to me.
The questions are at the end.

I have an interface:

```
public interface SimpleAgenda {

    public List<String> getAppointments();

    public String getAppointment(Date d);

    public void addAppointments(Date d, String label);

}
```

And a class that implements this interface:

```
public class MyAgenda implements SimpleAgenda {

    private Map<String, String> appointments;

    @Override
    public List<String> getAppointments() {
        List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println(this.appointments == null);
        for (String key : this.appointments.keySet()) {
            String label = this.appointments.get(key);
            lst.add(label);
        }

        return lst;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAppointment(Date d) {
        String dateString = d.toString();
        String app = this.appointments.get(dateString);
        
        return app;
    }

    @Override
    public void addAppointments(Date d, String label) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // this behavior is not implemented yet in this class
    }

}
```

And finally I have the test class:

```
// @RunWith attaches a runner with the test class to initialize the test data
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AgendaTest {

    private static final String LABEL = "This is a mock appointment for: ";

    // @InjectMocks annotation is used to create and inject the mock object
    @InjectMocks
    MyAgenda agenda = new MyAgenda();

    // @Mock annotation is used to create the mock object to be injected
    @Mock
    Map<String, String> mockedAppointments;

    @Before
    public void createMocks() {
        Date d1 = (new GregorianCalendar(120, 4, 15)).getTime();
        Date d2 = (new GregorianCalendar(119, 7, 31)).getTime();

        String key;

        key = d1.toString();
        // add the mocked behavior of for a set of given dates
        when(mockedAppointments.get(key)).thenReturn(LABEL + key);

        key = d2.toString();
        // 1. add the mocked behavior of for a set of given dates.
        // 2. Strict stubbing that requires that all declared stubs are actually used
        //    the statement lenient() relax this requirement. Check the manual. 
        lenient().when(mockedAppointments.get(key)).thenReturn(LABEL + key);

        when(mockedAppointments.size()).thenReturn(2);
    }

    @Test
    public void mockTest() {
        for (String key : mockedAppointments.keySet()) {
            String v = mockedAppointments.get(key);
// Do not worry, we will never reach this line. We are querying the object on 
// method that was not mocked (i.e. keySet).            
            Assert.fail();
        }

        int size = mockedAppointments.size();

        Assert.assertEquals(2, size);
    }

    @Test
    public void simpleTest() {
        int appCounter = agenda.getAppointments().size();
// Do not expect that appCounter is 2 (or more in general different than 0) ... 
// we are actually querying an object that was not mocked!!!
// See the details of the implementation of the method: MyAgenda.getAppointments()
        Assert.assertEquals(0, appCounter);
    }
```

These are my questions:

1. In `mockTest()` when i call `mockedAppointments.keySet()` it return an empty set... my question is: why `mockedAppointments.keySet()` doesn't throw a `nullPointerException` (mockedAppointments is only declared)? maybe because it's a mock? And if the reason is this, why doesn't a mock throw "nullPointerException"?
2. In `simpleTest()` we have `agenda.getAppointments().size();`; `agenda.getAppointments()` contains `System.out.println(this.appointments == null);` and this line prints "false" is i keep the @InjectMocks annotation, "true" otherwise, but why? In the first case (@InjectMocks is kept) where is the "appointments" attribute of "agenda" initialized? Is it initialized because we inject the value of `mockedAppointments` into it? If yes, does Mockito only do this based on the type of the mock defined in the test class and the type of the attribute defined in `MyAgenda`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Qn why mockedAppointments.keySet() doesn't throw a nullPointerException (mockedAppointments is only declared)? maybe because it's a mock? And if the reason is this, why doesn't a mock throw "nullPointerException"?
   Answer is : Because `mockedAppointments.keySet().size` is 0 and `mockedAppointments.keySet()` is empty, it is the behavior of the mock
2. 2.0 Qn System.out.println(this.appointments == null); line prints "false" is i keep the @InjectMocks annotation, "true" otherwise, but why?
   Answer is :   In junit or mockito System.out.println won't works, rather use logger.
   2.1 Qn In the first case (@InjectMocks is kept) where is the "appointments" attribute of "agenda" initialized? 
   Answer is : it is mocking the class and eg for list it initialize as 0 and keep value as empty, Inaddition to that

```
@InjectMocks
private MyAgenda agenda;
```

should be declared like this
2.2 Qn Is it initialized because we inject the value of mockedAppointments into it? 
Answer is : mockedAppointments and agenda doesn't have any connection, inaddition to that
Rather this injectMocks you can use `@Mocks`,it works.

```
 @Mocks
 private MyAgenda agenda;
```