# E.g. thenReturn() may be missing. Examples of correct stubbing: unit test in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

I am trying to unit test BookService class and I am very new to unit testing.
In project, I am using DTO's, and I am converting them back and forward as needed.

My test class looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration
class BookServiceTest {


    @InjectMocks
    BookService bookService;

    @Mock
    BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Mock
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;
    private BookDto bookDto = new BookDto();
    private Book book = new Book();


    @Test
    void addNewBook() {
        bookDto.setId(1L);
        bookDto.setTitle("Harry Potter");
        bookDto.setAuthor("J. K. Rowling");
        bookDto.setPublisher("Bloomsbury Publishing");
        bookDto.setCategory(Category.NEW);
        bookDto.setTotalCount(10);
        bookDto.setRented(0);

        book = modelMapper.map(bookDto, Book.class);

        Mockito.when(bookRepository.save(book)).thenReturn(book);
        assertEquals(bookService.addNewBook(bookDto), book);

    }
```

And when I run the test I get this error:

```
E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
 3. you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction is completed
```

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

```
    @Test
    void findBookById() {
        bookDto.setId(2L);
        bookDto.setTitle("Harry Potter");
        bookDto.setAuthor("J. K. Rowling");
        bookDto.setPublisher("Bloomsbury Publishing");
        bookDto.setCategory(Category.CLASSIC);
        bookDto.setTotalCount(10);
        bookDto.setRented(0);

        book = modelMapper.map(bookDto, Book.class);

        Mockito.when(bookRepository.findById(2L)).thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(book));
        assertEquals(book, bookService.findBookById(2L));
    }
```

And this part of code returns like id = 2 doesn't exist which is not true. It exists.

Same is for this code test

```
    @Test
    void allBooks() {

        BookDto bookDto = new BookDto();
        bookDto.setId(2L);
        bookDto.setTitle("Harry Potter");
        bookDto.setAuthor("J. K. Rowling");
        bookDto.setPublisher("Bloomsbury Publishing");
        bookDto.setCategory(Category.NEW);
        bookDto.setTotalCount(10);
        bookDto.setRented(0);

        BookDto bookDto1 = new BookDto();
        bookDto1.setId(3L);
        bookDto1.setTitle("1984");
        bookDto1.setAuthor("George Orwell");
        bookDto1.setPublisher("George Orwell Publishing");
        bookDto1.setCategory(Category.CLASSIC);
        bookDto1.setTotalCount(10);
        bookDto.setRented(2);

        List<BookDto> books = new ArrayList<>();
        books.add(bookDto);
        books.add(bookDto1);

        List<Book> bookList = Arrays.asList(modelMapper.map(bookDto, Book.class));

        Mockito.when(bookRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(bookList);
        assertEquals(bookDto, bookService.allBooks());


    }
```

it says `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: source cannot be null`

Comment: Side issue - `assertEquals(book, bookService.addNewBook(bookDto));` since the javadoc for assertEquals says expected first, actual second (https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertEquals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: @MrR thank you for your answer! :) May I please ask u one more question related to unit testing?

Comment: @MrR what do u mean?

Comment: Please post signature of BookRepository.save() method - the error seems to suggest it doesn't return a book.

Comment: And have you done - `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` somewhere (`@Before`?)?

Comment: No, as I mentioned I am very new to unit testing so any help is appreciated.

Comment: I do think something is not working with repository. I updated my question so you can check

Comment: This answer might help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/16467893 - we don't know which JUnit you are using (that link gives both 4 & 5 answers).

Comment: I changed what you said for `assertEquals(book, bookService.addNewBook(bookDto));` and it works fine now. :)

Comment: This `@Mock
    BookRepository bookRepository;` means use a "mocked" object.  That will only work if Mockito is properly initialised - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16467893 for examples of what to do, then if you are still getting the tips I'd suggest the method signature (return type) doesn't match - it's giving you what to look for / fix.

Comment: I have changed `@InjectMoc` for `BookService` to `@Mock` annotation and now test for `findById()` works fine. Now just `allBooks` :)

Comment: If you are testing `BookService` you either create an instance to test, or use @InjectMock - which means create an instance (presumably no arg constructor) - you don't use a Mock object as the thing to test - you can use Mock objects for everything around it.

Comment: But why it works then :/

Comment: My guess would be the "mock" version of `BookService` uses the mapper to get a `Book` ...

Answer (score 0):

Side issue. Your test is not a Spring Boot test but a "simple" JUnit test class with Mockito support. Therefore the top of your test class should be

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class BookServiceTest {
```

only.

Comment: Thank you for that note. I’m very new into junit testing and still trying to get my mind around it. So if you have any more advice fell free to add :)

Comment: I recommend reading the book "Test-Driven Development" from Kent Beck.