# How to use @InjectMocks when when some objects are to be injected via constructor and some without constructor?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I have a class:

```
classA
{
    private Boolean isEnable;

    private Config config;

    @Autowired
    private classC objC;

    public classA(Config config)
    {
        this.config = config;
        isEnable = config.getEnablingStatus();
    }

    public classB fun()
    {
        // Do something!
        // Return an object of classB!
    }
}
```

I want to create an object of this class in a test class, is this the right way to do it?

```
TestClassForClassA
{
    
    @Mock
    private classC objC;

    @Mock
    private Config config;
   
    @InjectMocks
    classA objA;

    @Before
    public void init() 
    {
        initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testFunWhenIsEnableIsTrue()
    {
       doReturn(true).when(config).getEnablingStatus();
       objA = new classA(config);
       // The reason for above 2 lines is, I want the isEnable to be set to true in objA.
       
       // Use the objA here for the futher logic!
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testFunWhenIsEnableIsFalse()
    {
       doReturn(false).when(config).getEnablingStatus();
       objA = new classA(config);
       // The reason for above 2 lines is, I want the isEnable to be set to false in objA.
       
       // Use the objA here for the futher logic!
    }
}
```

My concern is, will instantiating objects of classA in the above shown way - i.e. inside different test methods, inject the objects declared as mocks (using @Mock), into it?

If not what is the right way to do it?

Comment: You don't need `@InjectMocks` cause you creating a real object `new classA(config)`. If you wish to test a behavior of `classA` according to mocked `config` methods - you in right way

Comment: @Alex So, as I am creating a real object I can omit the 2 objects declared as @ Mock as well right? But if I do that, can I use them in doReturn().when()...?

Comment: If you need to inject all needed mocks without manual creation `classA` then you should use `@InjectMocks` but don't create object yourself `JUnit` will do it for you. Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467685/difference-between-mock-and-injectmocks