# How to fix unit test Missing Method Invocation Exception?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit4, springmockito

> When I run the test it shows the given error which I gave below.

> It shows Missing Method Invocation Exception Error. But I use that method in that test.

> I use Mockito to inject mockito.

> If anyone can solve this please help me.

[image]

> Entity

```
public class VesselInfo {

    private Long vesselId;

    private String ownerName;
}
```

> Service

```
@Service
public class VesselService {
    public List<VesselInfo> prepareMockVesselList(){
    
            List<VesselInfo> vesselMockDataList = new ArrayList<>();
            VesselInfo vesselInfo = new VesselInfo();
            vesselInfo.setVesselId(1L);
            vesselInfo.setOwnerName("Abdul Malek");
    
    }
    public List<VesselInfo> findVesselByOwnerNid(String ownerNid){
            List<VesselInfo> vesselMockDataList = new ArrayList<>();
            vesselMockDataList = prepareMockVesselList();
            List<VesselInfo> result = new ArrayList<>();
            for(VesselInfo vesselInfo : vesselMockDataList){
                if(vesselInfo.getOwnerNID().equals(ownerNid)){
                    //return vesselInfo;
                    result.add(vesselInfo);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
 }
```

> Test

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = SurveyServiceTest.class)
public class VesselServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    VesselService vesselService;
    @Test
    public void findVesselByOwnerNidTest(){

        // with valid Nid
        List<VesselInfo> vesselInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
        VesselInfo vesselInfo = new VesselInfo();
        vesselInfo.setOwnerNID("12341654565");

        VesselInfo vesselInfo1 = new VesselInfo();
        vesselInfo1.setOwnerNID("455454455");


        vesselInfoList.add(vesselInfo);
        vesselInfoList.add(vesselInfo1);


        when(vesselService.findVesselByOwnerNid("12341654565")).thenReturn(vesselInfoList);

    }
}
```

Comment: How are you configuring `vesselService` inside the test ?

Comment: now  update my code
if any thing you want to know let me know

Comment: `InjectMocks` creates a mock object (in this case `vesselService`) by injecting the dependencies which are defined using the `@Mock` annotation, have a look at this question for more information - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467685/difference-between-mock-and-injectmocks

Make sure you define the dependencies of `VesselService` using `@Mock` annotation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
@SpringBootTest
class ConservancyChargeServiceTests {

    @InjectMocks
    private TaxService taxService;

    @Mock
    private ICriteriaQueryAPI iCriteriaQueryAPI;

    @Mock
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Mock
    private TaxService _taxServiceTest;

public VesselInfo prepareVesselInfo(){
    VesselInfo vesselInfo = new VesselInfo();
    vesselInfo.setVesselId(1L);
    vesselInfo.setRegistrationNo("M16530");
    vesselInfo.setVesselNameEnglish("Surovi-8");

    return  vesselInfo;
}

public VesselTaxStatusResponse vesselTaxStatusResponse(VesselInfo vesselInfo) {

    VesselTaxStatusResponse vesselTaxStatusResponse = new VesselTaxStatusResponse();

    vesselTaxStatusResponse.setVesselInfo(vesselInfo);
    vesselTaxStatusResponse.setTaxPaidTill(LocalDate.now());
    vesselTaxStatusResponse.setValidityDate(LocalDate.now() );
    vesselTaxStatusResponse.setLastTaxPaidDate(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    vesselTaxStatusResponse.setPendingTaxAmount(150.00);

    return  vesselTaxStatusResponse;
}


public  List<VesselTaxStatusResponse> VesselTaxStatusResponseList(){

    List<VesselTaxStatusResponse> vesselTaxStatusResponseList = new ArrayList<>();

    VesselTaxStatusResponse vesselTaxStatusResponse = new VesselTaxStatusResponse();

    VesselInfo vesselInfo = new VesselInfo();

    Timestamp surveyDate = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    //dummy expiration date setup with current date + 10 days
    Timestamp surveyExpireDate = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() + 10 * 86400000 );
    // dummy certificate issue date for master
    Timestamp masterCertificateIssueDate = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() - 10 * 86400000);

    vesselInfo.setVesselId(1L);
    vesselInfo.setOwnerName("Abdul Malek");
    vesselInfo.setOwnerEmail("malek@gmail.com");
    vesselInfo.setOwnerNID("16352641582021");
    vesselInfo.setOwnerMobileNo("01677503555");
    vesselInfo.setOwnerPresentAddress("201, North Shajahanpur, Dhaka-1217");

    vesselInfo.setContactPersonName("Md. Kamrul Hasan");
    vesselInfo.setContactPersonMobileNo("01932145005");

    vesselInfo.setRegistrationNo("M164505");
    vesselInfo.setVesselType("Small");
    vesselInfo.setVesselNameEnglish("Surovi 8");
    vesselInfo.setVesselLength("317fit");
    vesselInfo.setVesselWidth("52 & 54 fit");
    vesselInfo.setVesselDepth("11.15 fit");
    vesselInfo.setSurveyDate(surveyDate);
    vesselInfo.setSurveyExpireDate(surveyExpireDate);
    vesselInfo.setSurveyPlace("Narayanganj");

    vesselInfo.setMasterName("Tawhid Noor");
    vesselInfo.setMasterAddress("101, Adabor, Dhaka-1005");
    vesselInfo.setMasterCertificateIssueDate(masterCertificateIssueDate);
    vesselInfo.setMasterGrade("A");
    vesselInfo.setMasterCertificateNo("153620");
    vesselInfo.setMasterNid("199265320158");

    vesselInfo.setDriverName("Abdul Mubin");
    vesselInfo.setDriverAddress("456/1, Mirpur DOHS, Dhaka-1213");
    vesselInfo.setDriverCertificateIssueDate(masterCertificateIssueDate);
    vesselInfo.setDriverCertificateNo("105400");
    vesselInfo.setDriverGrade("B");

    vesselInfo.setDayPassengerCapacityMain(300L);
    vesselInfo.setDayPassengerCapacityMiddle(100L);
    vesselInfo.setDayPassengerCapacityUpper(150L);
    vesselInfo.setDayPassengerCapacityTotal(550L);

    vesselInfo.setNightPassengerCapacityMain(250L);
    vesselInfo.setNightPassengerCapacityMiddle(75L);
    vesselInfo.setNightPassengerCapacityUpper(125L);
    vesselInfo.setNightPassengerCapacityTotal(450L);

    vesselInfo.setDaynoOfCabinSecondFloorSingle(10L);
    vesselInfo.setDaynoOfCabinSecondFloorDouble(8L);
    vesselInfo.setDaynoOfCabinThirdFloorSingle(12L);
    vesselInfo.setDaynoOfCabinThirdFloorDouble(10L);

    vesselInfo.setNoOfCrew(5L);
    vesselInfo.setNoOfSailor(10L);

    vesselInfo.setEngineName("Daihatsu");
    vesselInfo.setEnginePower("2000hp 6 cylinder");
    vesselInfo.setNoOfEngine(4L);


    vesselTaxStatusResponse.setVesselInfo(vesselInfo);
    vesselTaxStatusResponse.setTaxPaidTill(LocalDate.now());
    vesselTaxStatusResponse.setValidityDate(LocalDate.now());
    vesselTaxStatusResponse.setLastTaxPaidDate(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    vesselTaxStatusResponse.setPendingTaxAmount(150.00);

    vesselTaxStatusResponseList.add(vesselTaxStatusResponse);

    return vesselTaxStatusResponseList;
}

/**
 * @author Nobin
 */
@Test
void findPendingTaxByVesselOwnerId()  {

    List<VesselInfo> responseData = new ArrayList<>();
    VesselInfo vesselInfoResponseData = new VesselInfo();


    vesselInfoResponseData.setVesselId(1L);
    vesselInfoResponseData.setOwnerNID("16352641582021");

    responseData.add(vesselInfoResponseData);

    List<VesselInfo> vesselInfos = new ArrayList<>();

    VesselTaxStatusResponse vesselTaxStatusResponse = vesselTaxStatusResponse(prepareVesselInfo());


    when(this.restTemplate.exchange(anyString(), (org.springframework.http.HttpMethod) any(),
            (org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?>) any(), (Class<Object>) any(), (Object[]) any()))
            .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<Object>(HttpStatus.CONTINUE));

    when(this.jwtTokenProvider.generateToken((org.springframework.security.core.Authentication) any()))
            .thenReturn("foo");

    when(iTaxService.getVesselInfoByOwnerNid("16352641582021")).thenReturn(vesselInfos);
    when(iTaxService.findTaxStatusByVesselId(any(Long.class))).thenReturn(vesselTaxStatusResponse);

    List<VesselTaxStatusResponse> vesselTaxStatusResponseList = taxService.findPendingTaxByVesselOwnerId("16352641582021");

    assertNotNull(vesselTaxStatusResponseList);

}

}
```