# Mock instance variable that is already initiated

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am writing down jUnit for legacy code. Scenario is as below:

```
Class A{
     B b = new B(1,2,3);
 }
```

is there any way to **mock** or **override** **b** with object created by me with customer params.

Comment: Yes, by using reflection. There's a built-in way to do this with Mockito using `@InjectMocks`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467685/difference-between-mock-and-injectmocks

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider thanks, that worked. but what if initialisation in happening inside method. That mock value is getting override by the initialisation.

Comment: Not without changing at least some of the legacy code.  Option 1: inject a factory into `A` which knows how to create instances of `B`.  The test injects a  mock factory which can provide a mock `B`.  Option 2 (ugly): extract `b= new B(1,2,3)` to a protected method.  @Spy the instance being tested, and override that protected method to provide a mock `B`.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewS option 1 looks better.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, one way was to use `InjectMocks`, but since you were asking if there is a way to mock a constructor call if it is inside a method, the answer is yes, you can use Mockito's inline mock maker, and then mock the construction.

```
 assertEquals("foo", Foo.method());
 try (MockedConstruction mocked = mockConstruction(Foo.class)) {
     Foo foo = new Foo();
     when(foo.method()).thenReturn("bar");
     assertEquals("bar", foo.method());
     verify(foo).method();
 }
 assertEquals("foo", foo.method());
```

As per the official documentation, it is turned off by default

> This mock maker is turned off by default because it is based on completely different mocking mechanism that requires more feedback from the community. It can be activated explicitly by the mockito extension mechanism, just create in the classpath a file `/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` containing the value `mock-maker-inline`.

So I would suggest you to create that file, also you can refer to this section in the
[Official Mockito Documentation](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.2.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#Mocking_Final)

Do remember to add the latest version of mockito-inline maven dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-inline -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```